# Quick predicate logic and quantifier homework check (3)

Tags: logic

I need a quick check on my homework to see if any questions are wrong. We just finished learning quantifiers (for all, there exists) yesterday and the assignment is due today at 4pm MST. If it is wrong, please point me in the right direction or the answer/why.

[image]
 My answers:

(a) ¬Esd / ∀x(Exd → Exs) / ∀x(Exd ↔ Exs) / ¬Ess

(b) **NOT DONE** ⊢ (Lap → Pp) ∧ (Lpa → Ga)

For (b) I don't know how to symbolize the proper names with variables and quantifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

∀x [ Lax → (Gx ∧ Px) ] and the same for Philoponus.

(Lap → Pp ) ∧ (Lpa → Ga).